# i cant install angular linux

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

1. npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package:
   '@angular/cli@12.2.6', npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: npm WARN
   EBADENGINE    { node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0', npm WARN EBADENGINE
   npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', npm WARN EBADENGINE      yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
   }, npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v10.19.0', npm: '7.22.0'
   } } npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package:
   '@angular-devkit/architect@0.1202.6', npm WARN EBADENGINE
   required: npm WARN EBADENGINE    { node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0', npm
   WARN EBADENGINE      npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', npm WARN EBADENGINE
   yarn: '>= 1.13.0' }, npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node:
   'v10.19.0', npm: '7.22.0' } } npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine
   { package: '@angular-devkit/core@12.2.6', npm WARN EBADENGINE
   required: npm WARN EBADENGINE    { node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0', npm
   WARN EBADENGINE      npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', npm WARN EBADENGINE
   yarn: '>= 1.13.0' }, npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node:
   'v10.19.0', npm: '7.22.0' } } npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine
   { package: '@angular-devkit/schematics@12.2.6', npm WARN EBADENGINE
   required: npm WARN EBADENGINE    { node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0', npm
   WARN EBADENGINE      npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', npm WARN EBADENGINE
   yarn: '>= 1.13.0' }, npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node:
   'v10.19.0', npm: '7.22.0' } } npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine
   { package: '@schematics/angular@12.2.6', npm WARN EBADENGINE
   required: npm WARN EBADENGINE    { node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0', npm
   WARN EBADENGINE      npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6', npm WARN EBADENGINE
   yarn: '>= 1.13.0' }, npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node:
   'v10.19.0', npm: '7.22.0' } } npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine
   { package: 'open@8.2.1', npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node:
   '>=12' }, npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v10.19.0', npm:
   '7.22.0' } } npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library
   is no longer supported npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please
   upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use
   Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be
   problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details. npm
   WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see
   https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Answer (score 0):

It's your node version, it looks like it's v10.19.0 and Angular requires between 12.14.1 and below 14.0.0 [More info is here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20757).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubnt because of the part "node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0'"
">=14" i've always known as "larger o equal than 14" ...but here it seems to be smaller or equal. weird. So in short is how Meqwz says. you need a version between those